# Where I can subscribe a list of Javascript API to be obsoleted before the browser release?

Tags: javascript, firefox7

I am just hitting a bug due to Firefox 7 has removed some non-standard attribute (they have no moz- prefix) and cause my scripts fail on Firefox7.
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File

In order to prevent it happen again. I am interesting to get a list of API to be obsoleted. So that I can handle them before the browser release, without testing twenty alpha/beta/nightly build of browsers everyday.

It there any page, blog, or RSS who give warning before the feature disappear?

Comment: Do you mean specifically for Firefox, or for all of the leading browsers? Not sure about your current code, but for the future I'd suggest avoiding using any JavaScript features that are not part of the standard, especially features implemented by only one browser, and then you won't have to worry about them being removed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get fast and easy warnings about future changes. But here are some blogs for you, where you can read about changes that just got implemented:

- IE Blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/
- Opera Desktop Team - http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/
- Webkit changelogs in human language, by Peter Beverloo - http://peter.sh
- Firefox changelog monitor - http://www.squarefree.com/burningedge/